# Why is the captured image in device memory 0 bytes, but fully seen in the gallery?

Tags: cordova, cordova-3

I am using the following Cordova PhoneGap code to successfully capture an image and save it to internal memory, in this case, to DCIM/Camera in my Nexus 7. I am able to open the gallery and view the image captured there.

The problem is that when I plug the device into my PC and navigate to the folder, the images are there but of 0 bytes. Opening them in Photoshop, they are blank.

Why is the captured image in device memory 0 bytes, but fully seen in the gallery? How do I prevent the image from being 0 bytes when accessing from a PC?

```
    function onDeviceReady() {
        pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    }
// SHOOT PHOTO

// STEP 2. Show thumbnail
    function onPhotoFileSuccess(imageData) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(imageData));
      var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
      smallImage.style.display = 'block';
      smallImage.src = imageData;
    }
// STEP 1. Capture photo.
    function capturePhotoWithFile() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoFileSuccess, onFail, { quality: 90, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
          sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, 
          allowEdit : true,
          encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
       //   targetWidth: 200,
       //   targetHeight: 200,
          popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
          saveToPhotoAlbum: true  // saves photo to internal memory, viewed in Gallery
          });
    }
```

**My development environment**

Mac OS X 10.9.1 on latest Mac Mini

Cordova CLI 3.4.0

for Android 4.3, 4.4 v19

Testing in device: Android-19, Nexus 7 with 4.3 (cordova prepare/cordova compile)

Not for PG Build; no Jquery or other JS or CSS packages used

Comment: I can shoot with device's native camera and access those images on a PC for image editing. Just can't do so with Cordova's Camera API-captured images.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue now, did you get any solution for it. If yes please share. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check this jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/yvq5y/

I am sure it will help you with your answer as it did mine. Basically i used FileReader and got the base64 in its callback function (Check the Example). Then posted the base64 string to my WebService using AJAX post.

```
UploadImageToServer: function (imageURI) {
    app.convertFileToDataURLviaFileReader(imageURI, function (base64Img) {
        var a = base64Img;
        if (a.indexOf(",") > 0) {
            a = a.split(',')[1];
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'URL to post',
            data: { data: a },
            dataType: 'xml',
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                var status = $(response).find("string").text();
                if (status != "Failed") {
                   alert("Success!");

                }
                else {
                    alert("Status is failed!");
                }

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            }
        });

    });

}
```

Now the file reader function convertFileToDataURLviaFileReader is as below :

```
 convertFileToDataURLviaFileReader: function (url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function () {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            callback(reader.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.send();
}
```